# org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.reloc.org.apache.http.HttpEntity

Tags: android-studio

I have error :
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
Process: com.comm.a, PID: 4981
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.reloc.org.apache.http.HttpEntity
at com.comm.a.Utils.Connecter.connect(Connecter.java:123)
at com.comm.a.Utils.Sync.sendOrder(Sync.java:384)
at com.comm.a.Activity.Result$10.run(Result.java:919)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

```
 public static void connect(List<NameValuePair> params, Context context, File file) {
        setDate(context);
        checkError();
        Log.d("Anpah", "connect");
        try {
           // DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpClient defaultHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8");
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url + paramString);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Basic ");
            sb.append(Base64.encodeToString((login + ":" + password).getBytes(), 2));
            httpPost.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, sb.toString());
            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity =  MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            multipartEntity.addPart("sendOrder", new FileBody(file));
            httpPost.setEntity((HttpEntity) multipartEntity);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            content = responseEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Anpah_error", "Connect error 1 " + e.getMessage());
            setError(true);
            errorMsg = e.getMessage();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Anpah_error", "Connect error 2 " + e2.getMessage());
            setError(true);
            errorMsg = e2.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Anpah_error", "Connect error 3 " + e3.getMessage());
            setError(true);
            errorMsg = e3.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

build.gardle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.comm.a"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       // useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.9.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
  // implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:13.3.0@aar'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.5'

}
```